# ionic2 - embed youtube video play with no sound in iOS v10

Tags: ios, cordova, youtube, ionic2

I embed a `youtube` video in `ionic2` app:
**Page2.ts:**
    import {SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

```
export class Page2 {
  url: SafeResourceUrl;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
this.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/XHCVWWsQmUs');  
}
}
```

**Page2.html:**

```
<iframe height="190" onload="this.width=screen.width" [src]="url" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

And add some preferences for configurations:

**config.xml:**

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.youtube.com/*" />  
<allow-navigation href="*youtube*" />
<allow-navigation href="*ytimg*" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

It works fine on `android` device but **no sound** in `iOS`. I am getting this error in `XCode` console:

> 2016-11-08 10:06:10.648528 app[1066:438304] ERROR Internal navigation
>   rejected -  not set for url='about:blank'

Not sure if it is the issue affect the sound.

How can I resolve this? Could it be the bug from `Ionic` or `Cordova`?

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an older post but thought I'd try to revive it to see if anyone else might have a viable solution.

I have a similar issue with embedded YouTube video in an ionic v1 project. Note that I am using the AngularJS module to embed Youtube videos *ng-youtube-embed* found here:

https://github.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/ng-youtube-embed

Everything works as expected except for the audio on iOS. If the device is toggled to silent mode (with the hardware silent toggle button) the audio is muted. When the ringer is switched back on (hardware toggle) the audio plays back as expected. In researching this issue I keep coming across the that it is a problem with Cordova. That the audio is treated as a UI sound/sound effect and will not playback when the silent switch is on (the ringer off).

The only solution I have come across is half baked at best and have read some posts noting that their app was rejected by Apple because of the hackish solution (a plugin that forces a background audio sound). Otherwise it may be "That's just the way it is". :(

Comment: I am not sure how but I believe it is resolved. I did not do anything special other than update to the later version of `ionic`, if ever this info is helpful to you.